# CQL/Cassandra Rollback?

Tags: transactions, cassandra, atomic, rollback, cql

I've started to use Cassandra 1.2.0 few days ago and yesterday I realized that Rollback and commit are not supported. So I want to know if there is a way to simulate a rollback for a number of transactions ? I really need to do rollbacks as I'm developing and testing some new features in my project.
ps: I'm using Eclipse with cassandra-jdbc-1.1.2
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4):

Cassandra does not support transactions and therefore does not support commits and rollbacks.  You can often accomplish your goal in some other way, but it will require your application to manage it correctly; Cassandra won't do it for you.

Comment: thanks! when you mean that the application will have to do it by itself, what is a good strategy you recommend? Delete that row that was just inserted?

Comment: @asgs completely depends on the use case.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to achieve Transaction in Cassandra is to use QueryBuilder.Batch.  Use INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE to prepare CQLs & execute with Batch.Thats it.

Comment: Please improve your answer to a fully formed answer.